# How can I join a pandas dataframe with a geopandas using nereast values in a field

Tags: pandas, merge, geopandas

I have a geopdans dataframe that has a column called "values". I have a pandas dataframe that has a column called "values" as well. The column values in the two dataframes are not exactly the same; I would like to join them based on the nearest values for the geopnadas data frame.

Here is a minimal example of that I am intending to achieve, I have a geopadans data frame with a column "values":

```
   S_1_OBJECT    values  OBJECTID  Shape_Leng  Shape_Area  \
0      3541.0  325.5626         1    0.020833    0.000017   
1      3544.0  314.5491         2    0.029167    0.000026   
2      3545.0  551.1674         3    0.035000    0.000034   

                                            geometry  
0  POLYGON ((-115.6041666669581 50.96666666593393...  
1  (POLYGON ((-115.6 50.96666666593393, -115.6 50...  
2  (POLYGON ((-115.6 50.96249999897583, -115.6 50...
```

I also have a pandas data frame that has values column, for example:

```
     values  color  
0    300.00  green     
1    500.00   blue
```

eventually, I would like to have a geopandas data frame as such which link the color column to nearest values from geopandas data frame:

```
   S_1_OBJECT    values  OBJECTID  Shape_Leng  Shape_Area  color\
0      3541.0  325.5626         1    0.020833    0.000017  green 
1      3544.0  314.5491         2    0.029167    0.000026  green
2      3545.0  551.1674         3    0.035000    0.000034   blue

                                            geometry  
0  POLYGON ((-115.6041666669581 50.96666666593393...  
1  (POLYGON ((-115.6 50.96666666593393, -115.6 50...  
2  (POLYGON ((-115.6 50.96249999897583, -115.6 50...
```

I have checked merge for pandas but it seems there is no functionality as such. I also have tried:

```
shp_out = pandas.merge_asof(geopandasdataframe, pandasdataframe, on='values', direction='nearest')
```

but later I cannot convert the shp_out to json string using `shp_out.to_json()`

Comment: Can you show us the data and try to  provide a [minimal and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: added a simple example of that I would like to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue comes from `pandas.merge_asof` done on `geopadnas.GeoDataFrame`. It works, but on the resulting GeoDataFrame does not have assigned geometry which then breaks `.to_json()`. You can simply fix it by specifying geometry column after `merge_asof`.

```
shp_out = shp_out.set_geometry('geometry')
```

Then you should be able to get geojson via `shp_out.to_json()`.

EDIT: It also loses CRS, so I would recommend setting it back.

```
shp_out.crs = geopandasdataframe.crs
```